# 220 window unit into a 110

Tags: wiring

I have a 220 window a/c ..can I splice the cord with a 110 end if I do will it work or cause a fire or something also on the fuse panel can I run a jumper wire from an empty 110 slot to the slot that the window unit will be plugged into .would that double the power

Comment: Get a 120 volt unit or have an electrician put in a proper circuit.  Air conditionals don't work their best with the house burning down around them

Comment: Do not do what you are proposing. Do not do anything like what you are proposing. Electricity is very dangerous. If you knew enough to make something like this work, you would know enough not to do it.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I'm having trouble understanding what you want.  It seems pretty clear to me that this person has a 220v appliance but only a 110v outlet at that location.  So the question is how to make the A/C and outlet work together.  I can see asking for more information about the panel, the outlet, and the wiring in between them, but the question seems clear to me.  What seems unclear to you?  I would have thought that this would be just a replace outlet, wires/cable to the outlet, and add a 220v breaker on the panel with appropriate warnings about rerouting the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 6):

**Who pays your power?**  If it's you, you're going to go broke running a "hand-me-down" 240 volt air conditioner.  They are infamously inefficient.  It will actually be cheaper for you to buy a new 120V A/C than to power this old thing for a year.  And the new unit will cool better and be quieter. They're really cheap these days.

Just make sure you get a window unit, or a **2-hose** portable. [1-hose portables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-mBeYC2KGc) are wasteful and inefficient, and will cause condensation and mold in the rest of the house.

Scam alert: Avoid [the $50-100 units](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2horH-IeurA) that you pour water into - those are not air conditioners at all. (more like *extremely weak* swamp coolers that might cool a Barbie Doll house if the environment was very dry.  Swamp coolers are worthless in high humidity, so even Barbie and Ken would be out of luck.)

### No suicide cords, please

What you're talking about there is a "suicide cord".   If someone doesn't handle that cord exactly right, they can get shocked to death or badly burned.  It also may not work.

If the outlet is a dedicated one just for the air conditioner, any electrician can easily rejigger it to be a 240V outlet with a NEMA 6-15 or 6-20 socket.  It's straightforward enough work but there are many complications they could run into, so they really need pro level experience.